# Pre- and Post- Processing with mpi4py?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am wanting to write a script that would look like the following:

```
Execute a pre-processing function (only 1 process should do this; all others wait until this is done)
--------
All processes then do the main function in parallel
--------
Finally, after all processes finish, execute a post-processing function
```

I tried:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
*pre-processing
MPI.Init()
*parallel script
MPI.Finalize()
*post-processing
```

But all cores are running all parts of the script

Comment: Keep it easy and do not mix MPI with non MPI stuff in the same script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution that worked for me.
rank 0 is acting as a manager that pre-processes, then delegates the main script processing to all the other ranks, then post-processes. It works like this:

```
if rank == 0:
    pre_processing()
    for i in range(1,size):
        comm.sendrecv('pre-processing finished; ask for work', dest=i)
    while (work_remains):
        source = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
        comm.send(work_remains.pop(), dest=source)
    for i in range(1,size):
        comm.send('no more work', dest=i)
        comm.recv(source=i)
    post_processing()

else:
    comm.recv(source=0) # Blocker; wait for rank 0 to finish
    comm.send(rank, dest=0) # Ask for work
    main_script_processing()
```

Answer (score 0):

MPI does not spawn threads: each core runs your whole program. `MPI_Init` is not the start of a parallel region: it does stuff like buffer allocation, discovering the network.

So yes, everything before init and after finalize is executed by every process.

Solution: move `MPI_Init` all the way to the top, and execute the single-process stuff in an `if (myrank==0)` clause.

Answer (score -1):

When you `from mpi4py import MPI`, `MPI.Init()` is implicitly called.
This is also true for `MPI_Finalize()`: It's implicitly called when your python script exits.

You can test this via `MPI.Is_initialized()`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.